# Filling a specific region with a colour

Tags: matlab, fill, region, roi

As a follow up to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051686/applying-an-algorithm-to-a-specific-region-of-an-image/18055379#18055379), I want to ask if [fill](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) could work? I just didn't figure out what would be the values of `X` and `Y` be provided the question shown in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `imfill`?

http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/images/ref/imfill.html